# .htaccess reroute all to index.php with one variable and preserving $_GET

Tags: .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite, redirect, reroute

I would like to reroute ALL requests through index.php with one variable and preserving $_GET. If $_GET exists, it's always after first slash. Anything after first slash that's not $_GET should be ignored.
Something like this:

```
www.example.com/contact => www.example.com/index.php?page=contact
www.example.com/contact/ => www.example.com/index.php?page=contact
www.example.com/contact/?mod=add&id=4 => www.example.com/index.php?page=contact&mod=add&id=4
www.example.com/contact/ignore => www.example.com/index.php?page=contact
```

I'm not that good with .htaccess so I made just this (even thou I'm sure it's not really good)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,N]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,N,L]
```

First part is working OK, but I don't know how to make "ignoring" part. If I try to open www.example.com/contact/ignore I get 404 Not Found.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/.*$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,N,L]`

Comment: You're the man! Can you post it as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/.*$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,N,L]
```